# fadeIn callback doesn't work from inside jquery.ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I get some data using AJAX, prepend element to `body` and then display it. After it's displayed I need to perform some client-side operations on a new element (say, I need to render Latex using [codecogs' script](http://www.codecogs.com/latex/about.php)). My code looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
/* ... */
success: function(data){
    /* new element generation... */
    $(newelement).fadeIn(100, LatexIT.render('*'));
},
/* ... */ });
```

As you can see I call `LatexIT.render('*')` as a callback from fadeIn. It should perform whatever `LatexIT.render('*')` does right after the animation is over. But when called from `$.ajax success` the callback doesn't work, although fade itself occures normally.

**UPDATE**: I tried to replace `LatexIT.render('*')` with any simple function but it doesn't work. And `fadeIn(100, function () { LatexIT.render('*') });` **does** work when called from outside of ajax success.

Answer (score 2):

`LatexID.render('*')` is the syntax to *call* the `.render` method rather than bind it.  Unless that itself returns a function, which is unlikely, you need to use this syntax:

```
.fadeIn(100, function () { LatexIT.render('*') });
```

You could also do:

```
.fadeIn(100, LatexIT.render.bind(undefined, '*'))
```

assuming the browsers you need to support have [`.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: I tried to replace `LatexIT.render('*')` with any simple function but it doesn't work. Although `fadeIn(100, function () { LatexIT.render('*') });` **does** work when called from outside of ajax success.

Answer (score 1):

There you are not giving it a success callback, you are executing your render and giving what the render method returns to the complete argument of the fade animation, which is actually not a function that the animation can call at the end.

You should just wrap it into an anonymous function: 
`$(newElement).fadeIn(100, function() { LatexIT.render("*"); })`